# How to create a RAID1 btrfs with two disks and a mirror attached to each?

Tags: filesystem, raid, btrfs

I want to convert my ZFS pool to a btrfs filesystem because the ZFS performance is very poor. I had the following setup which was very easy to create using `zpool add` and `zpool attach`:

```
        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        data1       ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            sda     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdg     ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-2  ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdd     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdc     ONLINE       0     0     0
```

`sda` and `sdg` are two 5TB HDDs, `sdd` and `sdc` are two 4TB HDDs. Thus, a RAID1 setup spanning more than one set of mirrored devices.

Afaik for btrfs the RAID1 setup can be created at filesystem creation and with `btrfs convert`. However, I find no information how arguments passed to `mkfs.btrfs` or `btrfs device add` are interpreted. The same goes for `btrfs balance`.

I'm using Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: It is unclear what is the problem. There are many clear manuals on RAID creation on btrfs. You can make them using disks or partitions. Do you want one RAID1 on all 4 disks, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a RAID1 on those 4 disks by

```
sudo mkfs.btrfs -m raid1 -d raid1 /dev/sda /dev/sdg /dev/sdd /dev/cdc
```

All data and metadata will be mirrored.

`-m` and `-d` are set to store both data and metadata as RAID1. You don't need to care which data will be stored where.

On `btrfs` you don't set "hardcoded" mirrors.

You can mount the raid by choosing either of disks in a `mount` command.